# When I adding UITableView to subview, the cells aren't selectable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I have a custom class that is a `subclass` of `UIView`. I added a `UITextField` and a `tableview` as a `subview`. Then, in the `storyboard`, I set a `UIView's` class to the custom class.

The `tableview` I added in the custom class, extends larger than the initial `UIView`, (from the `storyboard`). So I changed `self.frame's` height.

When I run the app, I can type in the `textField` I added, but I can't select anything in the `tableview`. I can see the `cells`, but can't select them.

How can I make the `cells` selectable?

Here is the most relevant code:

```
_textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
[self addSubview:_textField];

CGRect tableViewsFrame = self.textField.bounds;
tableViewsFrame.origin.y += self.textField.bounds.size.height;
tableViewsFrame.size.height = 200;

_tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:tableViewsFrame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
[self addSubview:_tableView];

CGRect viewsFrame = self.bounds;
viewsFrame.size.height = self.textField.frame.size.height + self.tableView.frame.size.height + 100;
[self setFrame:viewsFrame];
```

Here is a link to a test project on Jumpshare: [testProject](http://jmp.sh/7ku83So)

Comment: Why you have used two tableView?

Comment: 1 is a overall tableview - a static one, 2 is a smaller tableview. I'm trying to create **my own** autoComplete UITextField.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You accidentally change the `Selection` of the `TableView` to `No Selection`.

[image]

**EDIT:**

You can add the `tableView` to the `window` like:

```
tableViewsFrame.origin = [self.superview convertPoint:self.frame.origin toView:self.window];
tableViewsFrame.origin.y += self.textField.frame.size.height;
_tableView.frame = tableViewsFrame;
[self.window addSubview:_tableView];
```

I have implemented a simple popup view：

```
@interface SimplePopupView : UIControl

+ (void)showView:(UIView *)view fromView:(UIView *)fromView;

@end

@implementation SimplePopupView

+ (void)showView:(UIView *)view fromView:(UIView *)fromView {
    UIView *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;

    SimplePopupView *popupView = [[SimplePopupView alloc] initWithFrame:window.bounds];
    [popupView addTarget:popupView action:@selector(dismiss) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [window addSubview:popupView];

    CGRect viewFrame = fromView.bounds;
    viewFrame.origin = [fromView convertPoint:fromView.frame.origin toView:window];
    viewFrame.origin.y += fromView.frame.size.height;
    viewFrame.size.height = 200;

    view.frame = viewFrame;
    [popupView addSubview:view];
}

- (void)dismiss {
    [self removeFromSuperview];
}

@end
```

then you can:

```
- (void)setupView {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    // Configure the TextField
    _textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    [_textField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    [self addSubview:_textField];

    // Configure the TableView
    _tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    _tableView.delegate = self;
    _tableView.dataSource = self;
    _tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    [SimplePopupView showView:_tableView fromView:_textField];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want the overall tableView to be "No Selection"

Comment: If you don't want to see the highlight background color, you can set the `Selection` of `UITableViewCell` to `None`.

Comment: Why not use the `Single Selection`?

Comment: I have 2 UITableViews. 1 - the UITableViewController. 2 - the tableView i added in the custom class - "SCAutoCompleteUITextField". I'm referring to the second 1. The one declared in SCAutoCompleteUITextField.

Comment: The `tableView` inside `SCAutoCompleteUITextField` is out of bounds of its superview(the cell), so it can't receive touch events.

Comment: What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Also, I don't think self.frame changes it's size

Comment: I found a "hack", but when I do it, the tableView gets positioned in the wrong place: `UIView *rootView = [self.window.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
                                                                                  [rootView insertSubview:self.tableView
                   belowSubview:self];`

Comment: Check my answer, will help you.

Comment: @Bannings Thanks!! It worked!! But now that it's added to self.window, I will have to remove the tableview in `viewWillDisappear`, right?

Comment: I will try it tomorrow. It's pretty late by me. 2:13 am. But thanks!!

Comment: I hoped this has helped you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not increasing your table view cell row height and adding content more than table view cell height.
Change textfield frame in your code like below, after you will able to select table view cell.

```
- (void)setupView
{
    // Configure the TextField
     _textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, 45)];
}
```

Also change your third table view cell height to more than 60 or similar to your view size. Then it will be selected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have 2 UITableViews. 1 - the UITableViewController. 2 - the tableView i added in the custom class - "SCAutoCompleteUITextField". I'm referring to the second 1. The one declared in SCAutoCompleteUITextField. So this didn't do the trick.

Comment: Mins you want to select first one.

Comment: I want to select the one in SCAutoCompleteUITextField. @Bannings gave a solution. But thanks anyway!! :)